# How to set three images horizontal in php

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set three images in horizontal but the images always comes out vertically
I have took reference from internet but still I cant solve this problem can someone please help me how to set it horizontally

```css
.categories{
    margin: 70px 0;
}
.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="categories">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="assets/offer.jpg">
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer2.jpg">
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer3.jpg">
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Clean and correct code helps to help you a lot. Please UPDATE your code ... there are MANY `<div>`'s in your code which are NOT closed ;-) And **THAN** you may have a look to the answer of VIO ... Setting up a flexbox grid needs a flex container ... just follow the links to see how it works.

Comment: sorry I have updated my code I  have put the flex now its working fine THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using Bootstrap try this code

```css
.categories{
    margin: 70px 0;
}
.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;
}
.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.row{
    flex-direction: row!important;
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="assets/offer.jpg">
                    </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer3.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
```

I list out some changes in your code

1. Close Every Divisions `<div></div>`
2. add row class like this

```
.row{
    flex-direction: row!important;
    display:flex;
}
```

if you are using bootstrap

1. Close Every Divisions `<div></div>`
2. add class in your HTML `d-flex flex-row`
   like this

```
<div class="categories">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="assets/offer.jpg">
                    </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/offer3.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much now its working fine and I have close every </div> tag

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:** I see you have used the flex-basis property. This property belongs to Flexbox and only works with Flex elements.

**The solution:**
You need to make `.row` a flex container like so:

```css
.row {
   display: flex; 
}
```

By the way, your 2nd and 3rd `col-3` don't have an ending tag. Please close them using an ending tag.

Some resources to learn Flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://flexboxfroggy.com

Comment: Thank you so much now its working fine and I have close all the </div>